# Why is my Flask app running on port 5000 even though I specified another containerPort in deployment.yaml file?

Tags: python, kubernetes, flask

I have a python app

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return jsonify({"hey":"test6"})
```

And a deployment.yaml file

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: mqttdemob
      namespace: default
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: mqttdemob
      strategy: {}
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: mqttdemob
        spec:
          containers:
          - image: ****/fluxdemo:main-584db7b6-1687862454 # {"$imagepolicy": "flux-system:mqttdemob"}
            name: app
            ports:
            - containerPort: 6000
```

And a service.yaml file

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: mqttdemob
    spec:
      selector:
        app: mqttdemob
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 6000
          targetPort: 6000
          nodePort: 30400
      externalIPs:
        - 1.2.4.122
      type: NodePort
```

When I deploy using these files I would want the Flask app to run on port 6000 which then would be forwarded to 30400.

But when I run

`kubectl exec <pod name> -- netstat -tulpn`

It outputs

```
 Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/python
```

Such that it is not using port 6000 but port 5000.

What am I doing wrong and how can I make sure that Flask will use port 6000 instead of 5000?

Comment: The app is running on default port.  Kindly change the flask port using 

if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=6000)

Answer (score 2):

`containerPort` is only informational and doesn't configure the port your app is running on.

You flask application is using its default port.
Try changing it in you main file where you are starting your server using:

```py
port = 6000 #you can change it to any unused port.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port)
```

- unused in the above case means the port which is currently not in use.